# Atomic tests with Qunit

Tags: atomic, qunit, sinon

I thought I was doing a reasonable job of writing atomic tests with Qunit. I thought I should introduce QUnit module() constructs to group related tests, however the second test here always fails when run with all the others, but passes when selecting 'rerun'. This suggests that my test setup isn't atomic and I don't understand the documentation!

Edited original question here, prepared a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrismcginlay/dom8bLk0/2/) which demonstrates the failure.

```
function cycle_and_progress() {
    return;
}

module("Traffic light is bound to cycle_and_progress", {
    setup: function (assert) {
        cycle_and_progress = sinon.mock();
    },
    teardown: function (assert) {
        cycle_and_progress.reset();
    }
});

test("Double click on LO triggers cycle_and_progress", function () {
    $('img#LO8').dblclick();
    equal(cycle_and_progress.calledOnce, true, 'c_and_p called after dblclick on LO');
});

test("Double click an SC triggers cycle_and_progress", function () {
    $('img#SC1').dblclick();
    equal(cycle_and_progress.calledOnce, true, 'c_and_p called after dblclick on SC');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img[id^='SC'], img[id^='LO']").dblclick(function() {
        cycle_and_progress($(this))
    });
});
```

Where I am going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I don't see what the purpose of `cycle_and_progress` is... you create it with `sinon.mock()`, but you aren't passing anything into sinon to mock out, so that just returns an empty function that would never be called, right? Am I missing something? What are you trying to mock out?

Comment: cycle_and_progress() is called when user double clicks either specified image id. (The real implementation performs a 3-state toggle of the image src attribute and it works in practice - I'm trying to figure out how to test it - will be doing full TDD next time around!) So, what I intended the test code to do was to replace the cycle_and_progress function with sinon.mock() and see under which circumstances it is called. Added a working JSFiddle to show error. Thanks.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrismcginlay/dom8bLk0/3/)